# how can i change the dpi of an image with the imagick extension

Tags: php, dpi, imagick

I need to change all uploaded files to 72 dpi.
I'm using the php imagick extension.

heres what i've tried (the image i'm using is 300dpi):

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setResolution(72,72) ;
$image->readImage($img);
$image->resampleImage  (72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$image->writeImage($target)
```

this doesn't seem to anything.
the image is uploading, but stays at 300dpi

Comment: Why do you care about DPI? Are you intending to print the images on paper?

Comment: i care because 1. the file sizes are huge and 2. internet explorer is not displaying them

Answer (score 11):

MatTheCat's answer is spot on. You might also try `setImageUnits()` to ensure it's working with inches and not centimeters.

```
$image->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$image->setImageResolution(72,72);
```

Resampling isn't necessary just to change dpi.

Note that changing the dpi alone will not affect file size and only applies to resampling and printing.

Comment: Whoever finds this: if reading a PDF and it's too small, use `setResolution` (and not `setImageResolution`) *before* imagick reads that PDF; follow @MatTheCat's link for more info.

Comment: @aexl THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to use setImageResolution rather than setResolution : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagick-setresolution.php#95533

Answer (score 0):

use this its work with imagick extension :

```
$finalImageOnline = $canvas->getCore(); //get Imagick object
    $finalImageOnline->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
    $finalImageOnline->setImageResolution(72,72);
    $finalImageOnline->resampleImage  (72,72,imagick::FILTER_SINC,1);
    $finalImageOnline->setImageFormat("jpg");
    file_put_contents ($this->path . '/' . 'online' . '/' .$namaFile.'.jpg', $finalImageOnline);
```