# Change in dpi using imagick library in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, dpi

We are adding some text using annotateimage function using imagick library in php. Source file is in 300 dpi, but after editing, output file becomes 96 dpi.

How can we fix it?

```
EDIT******************************
```

When we try this in our local development server, output file is also showing at 300 dpi. This issue is coming only when we test this in our web server. Both are linux and Imagick versions are also same.

Comment: Heya, can you post us your command code?

Comment: We are using annotateimage and writeimage functions from imagick php library

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i change the dpi of an image with the imagick extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907785/how-can-i-change-the-dpi-of-an-image-with-the-imagick-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setResolution for this, as an equivalent to the -density commandline switch.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setresolution.php

Edit:

You have to set this before reading the image for this to work.

```
$im = new Imagick(); 
$im->setResolution(300,300); 
$im->readImage("image.jpg");
```

Comment: We tried using this function (setResolution(300,300)) But there was no change in the output...

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. But we cannot call Imagick() contsructor without any parameter. The source file we are reading is in 300 dpi only. It is changing to 96 dpi after we edit it....

Answer (score 0):

First try this with Imagick

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$image->setImageResolution(300,300);
```

If above doesn't work try this.

You can read file and convert DPI of image from 96 to 300. Try this.

```
  $imageGet = file_get_contents($imagePath);
  if($imageGet){
     $imageConverted = substr_replace($imageGet, pack("cnn", 1, 300, 300), 13, 5);
     $savefile = file_put_contents($newimagePath, $imageConverted);
  }
```